# Spring Boot Docker - connection to localhost:5432 refused

Tags: spring-boot, docker, localhost

I am new to Docker. I am trying to dockerize my Spring Boot application but getting the error
**connection to localhost:5432 refused** .
The Spring Boot application has a postgresql db connection and uses random port to run on Tomcat.
Please find the details below, requesting to please check and help in resolving the issue. Please give a detailed solution as I am new to Docker.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/SpringConversionFactor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

**Docker run**

```
docker run springconversionfactor
```

**Exception**

```
Connection to localost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are running any application in docker it gets isolated from your existing environment.Here you are running spring boot application in docker and provided postgresql url as **localhost:5432**,because of that your spring boot application is finding postgres db inside your spring boot docker container.Please make sure *where your postgres db is running*.If it is running on your server give url as **server_ip:5432** or if it is running in other conatiner then give it as **container_name:5432** (here you can do port mapping with your server also).